# QValidator для QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, валидация

Какие нужно сделать условия, чтобы в виджете QLineEdit при написании текста, а затем при нажатии на кнопку принятия ("ОК"), были подходящими только такие слова, как: м, ж, муж, жен, мужской, женский? То есть можно было бы вводить только пол в нескольких вариациях.

[image: функция]

Самое сложное, вероятно, будет там, где возвращается Intermediate, так как, например, "мж" не является ошибочной фразой, однако её нужно доработать.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам больше подойдет готовый класс `QRegExpValidator` или заменить `QLineEdit` на `QComboBox`, избавив пользователя вообще вводить что-либо с клавиатуры.